# How to fix "ERRO[0005] error waiting for container: context canceled" when run hello-world with docker

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I installed Docker CE following https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/.
It seems I successfully installed it, but I got an error when I run hello-world. How can I fix this?

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS, installed in Chromebook.

```
(base) (xenial)spkaikai@localhost:/$ docker run hello-world
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:275: applying cgroup configuration for process caused \"open /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset/docker/cpuset.cpus: no such file or directory\"": unknown.
ERRO[0005] error waiting for container: context canceled
```

Below is my info of Docker.

```
(base) (xenial)spkaikai@localhost:/$ docker info
Containers: 4
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 4
Images: 11
Server Version: 18.09.5
Storage Driver: vfs
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
 Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: bb71b10fd8f58240ca47fbb579b9d1028eea7c84
runc version: 2b18fe1d885ee5083ef9f0838fee39b62d653e30
init version: fec3683
Security Options:
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 3.18.0-19095-g86596f58eadf
Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 4
Total Memory: 3.756GiB
Name: localhost
ID: Y4HI:IBME:EULW:5LU3:Q3ZT:EMEN:LOUU:P7AZ:JMH4:PU7G:6DR5:2SSY
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
Product License: Community Engine

WARNING: No memory limit support
WARNING: No swap limit support
WARNING: No kernel memory limit support
WARNING: No oom kill disable support
WARNING: No cpuset support
WARNING: bridge-nf-call-iptables is disabled
WARNING: bridge-nf-call-ip6tables is disabled
```

Comment: Check `ls /sys/fs/cgroup` to see which cgroup controllers you have. If `cpuset` is there, check `ls /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset/docker` to see whether there is a cgroup `docker` for this controller. Also check `journalctl -eu docker` to see the logs of Docker daemon - look for errors, warnings, and everything related to cgroups.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! I checked but I cannot find ```docker```  in ```/sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset```. How can I add the file..?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem recently. I just uninstalled the docker by using  `apt-get autoremove docker-ce` and then reinstalled docker-ce. After 
that everything was fine. All the images are still there.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem recently.  Look for old crap in /usr/local/bin (ctr, containerd*, docker-compose,etc..) and remove it.